# cut off overlapping plots in multiple plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, overlapping

i do this code and it was good.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

epsilon = np.linspace (0.001 , 1 ,50)

plt.figure(figsize = (18,7) , dpi = 80)

fig = Figure()

nu_1 = np.linspace ( 0.3, 0.3 , 50)
N = np.linspace (0 , 60 , 50)
N = ((2*(8.8 *10**(-9) - ((8.8 *10**(-9))+(3.513))/(8.8 *10**(-9))))/epsilon*(4*(3.513)+1)**(1/2))* np.arctanh(nu_1)

nu_2 = np.linspace ( 0.2, 0.2 , 50)
M = np.linspace (0 , 60 , 50)
M = ((2*((1.007 *10**(-6)) - ((1.007 *10**(-6))+(3.855))/(1.007 *10**(-6))))/epsilon*(4*(3.855)+1)**(1/2))* np.arctanh(nu_2)

nu_3 = np.linspace ( 0.4, 0.4 , 50)
L = np.linspace (0 , 60 , 50)
L = ((2*((6.72 *10**(-7)) - ((6.72 *10**(-7))+(2.68))/(6.72 *10**(-7))))/epsilon*(4*(2.68)+1)**(1/2))* np.arctanh(nu_3)

plt.subplot(1 , 3 , 1)

plt.plot(N , epsilon , color = 'firebrick' , linewidth = (1) ,  label = r'$  \xi = 1.6 \times 10^{-3}  $')
plt.legend (loc='upper left' , fontsize = 15)
plt.xlabel('Number of E-folds', fontsize = 19)
plt.ylabel('$\epsilon_2$', fontsize = 19)
plt.xticks([0 ,10,20,30,40,50 , 60], fontsize = 13)
plt.yticks([0.00001 , 0.0001 ,0.001 ,0.01 , 0.1 , 1], fontsize = 13)

plt.subplot(1 ,3 , 2)

plt.plot(M , epsilon , color = 'darkgreen' , linewidth = (1) , label = r'$  \xi = 1.4 \times 10^{-5}  $')
plt.legend(loc='upper left' , fontsize = 15)

plt.xlabel('Number of E-folds' , fontsize = 19)
plt.ylabel('$\epsilon_2$' , fontsize = 19)


plt.xticks([0 ,10,20,30,40,50 , 60] , fontsize = 13)
plt.yticks([0.00001 , 0.0001 ,0.001 ,0.01 , 0.1 , 1], fontsize = 13)


plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)

plt.plot (L , epsilon , color = 'navy' , linewidth = (1) ,  label = r'$ \xi = 2.1 \times 10^{-5}  $')
plt.xlabel('Number of E-folds' , fontsize = 19)
plt.ylabel('$\epsilon_2$' , fontsize = 19)
plt.legend(loc='upper left' , fontsize = 15)

plt.xticks([0 ,10,20,30,40,50 , 60] , fontsize = 13)
plt.yticks([0.00001 , 0.0001 ,0.001 ,0.01 , 0.1 , 1], fontsize = 13)

plt.tight_layout(6) 

plt.show()
```

[the first result in subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC6ay.png)
But when I want to plot all these figures in one plot, 2 of them are cut and just one of them is complete. what should i do in this regard?
is the problem related to the overlapping? i want to see the overlapping of all these figures.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

epsilon = np.linspace (0.001 , 1 ,50)

plt.figure(figsize = (7,5) , dpi = 80)

fig = Figure()

nu_1 = np.linspace ( 0.3, 0.3 , 50)
N = np.linspace (0 , 60 , 50)
N = ((2*(8.8 *10**(-9) - ((8.8 *10**(-9))+(3.513))/(8.8 *10**(-9))))/epsilon*(4*(3.513)+1)**(1/2))* np.arctanh(nu_1)

nu_2 = np.linspace ( 0.2, 0.2 , 50)
M = np.linspace (0 , 60 , 50)
M = ((2*((1.007 *10**(-6)) - ((1.007 *10**(-6))+(3.855))/(1.007 *10**(-6))))/epsilon*(4*(3.855)+1)**(1/2))* np.arctanh(nu_2)

nu_3 = np.linspace ( 0.4, 0.4 , 50)
L = np.linspace (0 , 60 , 50)
L = ((2*((6.72 *10**(-7)) - ((6.72 *10**(-7))+(2.68))/(6.72 *10**(-7))))/epsilon*(4*(2.68)+1)**(1/2))* np.arctanh(nu_3)

plt.xticks([0.00001 ,10 ,20 ,30 ,40 ,50 , 60] , fontsize = 10)
plt.yticks([0.00001 ,0.0001 ,0.001 ,0.01 ,0.1 , 1] , fontsize = 10)
plt.plot(N , epsilon , color = 'firebrick' , linewidth = (1) , label = r'$  \xi = 1.6 \times 10^{-3}  $')
plt.plot(M , epsilon , color = 'darkgreen' , linewidth = (1) , label = r'$  \xi = 1.4 \times 10^{-5}  $')
plt.plot (L , epsilon , color = 'navy' , linewidth = (1) , label = r'$ \xi = 2.1 \times 10^{-5}  $')
plt.legend(loc='upper left' , fontsize = 14)

plt.xlabel('Number of E-folds' , fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('$\epsilon_2$' , fontsize = 15)
plt.show()
```

[the red circle is the place where plots are cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNlXr.png)

what should I do? i wanna see the overlapping.

Comment: The main problem is that all 3 curves are so close that visually they appear on the same spot.  Further, some things look weird. Such as `nu_1 = np.linspace (0.3, 0.3, 50)` which creates an array filled with the same number. If that is intended, it is better to set `nu_1 = 0.3` and let numpy's broadcasting taking care of extending it internally to an array. Also, when `N = np.linspace(...)` directly followed by `N = ...` the `linspace` result never gets used. Best to leave it out.

Comment: Your expressions for `N`, `M` and `L` are all negative, while the xticks are all positive. Maybe you want to negate the expression.  That will show everything onto the plot, although `N` goes much more to the right than the other ones. You also might want to put a logscale as in `plt.yscale('log'); plt.xscale('log')`, depending on what exactly you want to visualize.

Comment: thank you JohanC for your help. I can not change the expression. this is what I have achieved after doing some complicated calculations. I changed to nu_1 as you mentioned, thanks, but the whole problem has still remained.

Comment: Well, if your numbers are all negative, you should set the ticks of the x-axis to negative, for example `plt.xticks([-0.00001,-10,-20 -30,-40,-50,-60])`.  For a negative axis you could set a "symmetrical logscale": `plt.xscale('symlog')`